# What can you say about the real numbers x and a if you are told that for every $\epsilon > 0, |x-a| < \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis

It seems to me as though the asnwer is that $x$ and $a$ are equal to each other, and $|x-a| = 0$. 
I'm unsure since the next part of the question says:

What if you are told that, for every positive integer $n, |x-a| < \frac{1}n$

This second part also seems like the answer is $x=a$ to me, is this correct, that $x=a$ for both scenarios? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's right in both cases. (To further convince yourself, suppose $x \ne a$. Then you can find some $\epsilon$ or $n$ such that the inequality is violated.)

Comment: The second questions is to let you see that the 'for all $\epsilon>0$' can be weakened to only require a 'for all $1/n$ with $n$ natural' and still get the same result.

Comment: Ah I see, good point, many thanks for the replies

Comment: For the 1st one, if $x\ne a$ then $|x-a|$ is not less than the positive number $|x-a|$, so $|x-a$| cannot be less than $every$ positive number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct for both scenarios, but for different reasons.

The first inequality with $\epsilon$ is true in any ordered field. It's pretty much a tautology in terms of the symbols being used; to prove it, just shuffle the symbols around.

The second inequality with $n$ is true in the real numbers by virtue of some special information that you need to know about the real numbers. In particular, you need to know that $\mathbb R$ is Archimedean. So your proof will need to include the word "Archimedean" at some point, or else invoke some equivalent property.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|x-a|$ is a non negative constant.

Now if $$|x-a|<\epsilon $$ for every positive $\epsilon $you can use squiz theorem to get $|x-a|=0$ 
Same argument works for $1/n$.